# Access VBA: Determine remote user

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I am working with an Access Database and want to see the user name that is logged in.

On the terminal server that they remote into, if in the command prompt if you type

```
echo %ClientName%
```

with VBA, it will return the correct information.

How to simulate this with VBA and the onOpen Event.

Comment: use win32 api call: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161394

Comment: alternatively, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337237/using-vb6-how-do-i-get-the-current-user-and-domain-on-windows-xp

Answer (score 0):

%username% contains username. Type set in command prompt to see other variables.

**Environ Function**

Returns the String associated with an operating system environment variable.

**Syntax**

```
Environ({envstring | number})
```

The Environ function syntax has these named arguments:

**Part 
Description**

*envstring* Optional. String expression containing the name of an environment variable.

*number* Optional. Numeric expression corresponding to the numeric order of the environment string in the environment-string table. The number argument can be any numeric expression, but is rounded to a whole number before it is evaluated.

**Remarks**

If envstring can't be found in the environment-string table, a zero-length string ("") is returned. Otherwise, Environ returns the text assigned to the specified envstring; that is, the text following the equal sign (=) in the environment-string table for that environment variable.

If you specify number, the string occupying that numeric position in the environment-string table is returned. In this case, Environ returns all of the text, including envstring. If there is no environment string in the specified position, Environ returns a zero-length string.