# How to read user name in Windows Server 2012 with Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2012-r2, objectcontext

I have an old program made with Visual Basic 6.0. This program is run under MTS/COM+ on the server as business logic to supply data for the clients. It uses an ObjectContext object to obtain the user name who is using the client part of the application and thus calling the business logic.

```
Implements ObjectControl
Private m_ctx As ObjectContext
Set m_ctx = GetObjectContext()
l_nm_user = m_ctx.Security.GetDirectCallerName
```

However, for some reason, in Windows Server 2012 R2 GetDirectCallerName returns an emty string. This piece of code works nicely at least in Windows Server 2008 R2 and previous versions.

The following libraries are referred in the project:

```
stdole2.tlb - OLE Automation
COMSVCS.DLL - COM+ Services Type Library
```

What should I change to make this work also in Windows Server 2012 R2 and to return the user name correctly, so to return at least something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using VB6, how do I get the current user and domain on Windows XP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337237/using-vb6-how-do-i-get-the-current-user-and-domain-on-windows-xp)

Comment: Is `GetObjectContext` coming from MTS/COM+ library reference? If so, this might be a different user than current execution context username, particularly when RMI is involved.

Comment: Yes, GetObjectContext is coming from MTS/COM+.